# MatplotLib problems in Python 3.6 Conda environment Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, anaconda

I started with a Conda 3.7 installation, but needed to add a 3.6 environment in order to use Tweepy.  That worked fine.  Now I am trying to add a WordCloud using MatPlotLib and WordCloud.  I installed these into the 3.6 environment using Conda. No errors were reported.  When I try to run my code, nothing happens. No chart, no error, nothing. 
If I try just running Matplotlib in the 3.6 environment with this simple code, I also get no output at all.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

If I run just the import statement from an Anaconda 3.6 command prompt, it throws me out of Python, back to a C prompt, with no error message.

Obviously my environment is messed up, but reinstalling everything did not help.   I reinstalled with

```
conda install matplotlib --channel conda-forge
```

[image: This is from Conda List]

The image above is from conda list.  Suggestions welcome.  UPDATED.

Comment: Those seem to be totally different problems. Concerning the first one. Do you by chance have a file named `wordcloud.py` in your current working directory? Concerning the second problem, this might be something very deep and I would expect a new install to be needed.

Comment: You are right about the wordcloud.py - silly mistake on my part.  Thanks.  That just leaves the matplotlib problems.

Comment: The more information you provide, the higher the chances to find the problem. So remove the first problem from this question. But add everything that would allow someone to reproduce the second one.